# CSS Fixing divs in place and hiding overflows

Tags: html, css, layout, overflow, css-position

So, I've been stuck with this problem for a while now and I can't seem to find a solution.

I'm trying to make a layout consisting of (for now) 4 different content areas like so:
[image: Basic layout]

### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to do the following things:

Simple explanation: `Content` should be the only scrollable thing on the page, with the `footer` following right behind it if content fits on the page, fixed on the bottom otherwise.

Detailed explanation:

- Fix `banner` and `mainMenu` so that they never move when page is scrolled.
- Make the `content` scroll with a page so that:

  - If the `content` (and `footer`) fit on a page, no scroll is displayed.
  - If the scroll is needed, `content` goes behind the `banner` (not being shown) and does not appear again above it.
  - If the scroll is needed, `content` can scroll until the bottom line of it and the `footer` are in the visible area.
- The `footer` should do two things:

  - If `content` and `footer` fit on the page, `footer` should stick at the bottom of the `content`
  - Otherwise, `footer` should be fixed on the bottom.

### What I have tried

Fixing `banner`,`mainMenu` and the `footer` are fixed using `position: fixed` (and positioned accordingly). Parent `div` has `overflow: hidden` (which doesn't seem to work).

```
<div id='main'>
  <div id='banner'>banner</div>
  <div id='mainMenu'>mainMenu</div>
  <div id='content'>.. some long content ..</div>
  <div id='footer'>footer</div>
</div>
```

And

```
#main {
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 40px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#main #banner {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}
#main #mainMenu {
  width: 230px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  top: 140px;
}
#main #content {
  width: 720px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#main #footer {
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  clear: both;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

### The Problem

Footer does not follow `content` if it fits within the area
[image: Footer does not follow content]
Content overflows on the top of banner
[image: Content overflows over banner]

I would really prefer to do this just in CSS (if possible) and as compatible as possible (IE7+, all other major browsers). 
It's really getting frustrating now.. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `position:fixed` fixes elements to _view port_ instead of parent elements:[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position#Values)

Comment: @Passerby: That's what I'm looking for for `banner` and `content`. I just can't figure out how to deal with the overflow of `content` and `footer` behaving in two different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no conceivable way I can think of that would solve your problem by just using css. Once you have set your elements to a fixed position they are out of the flow and thus your other elements cannot conform around them.

However I did find a solution by doing two different things. For the header issue I simply added another fixed element above the main banner and set it to the color of the background. This way the content will scroll behind it and look as if it is hidden. For the footer, I set up some javascript using jQuery to see if the content overflows or not. If it does then the footer's position is set to fixed, otherwise the position is set to relative.

You can check it all out here in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrQGh/4/

To test out the javascript simply delete the text until there is no more overflow and run it again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I really like your solution :) There's one little problem (my fault for not mentioning it in the question): the background is intended to have a `background-image` (which can be set dynamically) hence using a `hider` div like that can become a little bit tricky (although not impossible). Is there any other solution for this, or should i start coding background for the hider? :)

Comment: That's tough, I was hoping you didn't have a background image. Will have to thinks about another solution.